# failed to send sms in jasmin sms gateway, Mandatory argument [to] is not found

Tags: python, python-2.7, sms-gateway, jasmin-sms

I am working on Jasmin SMS gateway, im follow the documentation. create user,group, mtrouter and success binding to  my provider. but when i try send sms
http://127.0.0.1:6600/send?username=ojgr12hnds&password=123ggfds&to=62852740&content=hello

jasmin response is Error "Mandatory argument [to] is not found."

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Restful API then you need proper JSON structure. In case of http api try testing using curl:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:6600/send? -d 'username=ojgr12hnds&password=123ggfds&to=62852740&content=hello'
```